# Is a foreign key constraint on a table created just to resolve a multi valued attribute good design?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

In my ER model, I have an entity type 'City' which has a multi valued attribute of ZIPCode. So far, so good.

Now when, I translate my ER model into relational schema, I create an extra table to resolve the multi valued ZIPCode Attribute. Something like `CityZIP(CityID, ZIPCode)` with the composite primary key: CityID, ZIPCode

Now lets say, I am storing the address of an employee in an employee table which must store the City & ZIP Code. One way to do this would be to have two columns CityID, ZIP in my employee table with a foreign key constraint on the CityZIP table.

But is this even allowed? I am referencing a table which is not an entity per se according to my ER diagram but only created to resolve the multi valued ZIP Attribute.

Comment: The answer is almost certainly "yes, this is ok", but the reason and rationale behind it is long winded, convoluted, and belongs in a data modeling discussion group or classroom, as any number of sub-topics and explanations will come up depending on what you're actually dealing with. Too, just because it can be done does not mean it should be done--but that, too, depends on what your are modeling.

Comment: Time to read a published academic textbook on information modeling & database design. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not textbooks on doing information modeling & database design.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is "allowed". It is a perfectly reasonable design, at least as long as ZIP codes may span cities (i.e. the functional dependency { ZIPCode } -> { CityID } doesn't hold).

That a table doesn't correspond directly to an entity in an ER model, doesn't mean that you can't reference it with foreign keys in a relational model. The models are independent in that regard, and there is no single "correct" mapping between them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Much appreciated.